# annotation.kotlin_module:Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin.Binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0,expected version is 1.6.0

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin, kotlin-multiplatform

Due to "**duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0**" error , I have updated  kotlinVersion = "1.6.0" to kotlinVersion = "1.8.0".
But now i am getting this error **/Users/abc/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation-jvm/1.6.0-beta01/a7257339a052df0f91433cf9651231bbb802b502/annotation-jvm-1.6.0-beta01.jar!/META-INF/annotation.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.**.
Tried everything but nothing works.

If anyone has solution for this, Please share with us. Thank you.

Comment: See discussion in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-55048/The-binary-version-of-its-metadata-is-1.7.1-expected-version-is-1.5.1.. Try to upgrade every library and plugin to latest versions.

Comment: I had a similar issue and solved it by the suggestions from: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew18.html#usage-of-the-latest-kotlin-stdlib-version-in-transitive-dependencies  Specifically for me it was the `implementation platform('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0'))` that fixed it

Comment: @Umair Khan , did you solved the issue?